# How to pass arguments using FFMPEG

Tags: c#, command-line, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use the `ffmpeg` library in my program. With the code I've written, I get:

> At least one output file must be specified

Previously I tried to do with `ffplay` command, but I get an error:

> ffplay: Invalid argument

I can't understand the reason. Can you help me?

```
public void Func()
{
    string FFMPEG_PATH = Path.Combine(
        Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), @"C:\Ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe");

    string strParam = @"-f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv444p -s 720x576 -i C:\Users\Cenk\Desktop\Dosyalar\cenk444.yuv";
    process(FFMPEG_PATH, strParam);
}

public void process(string Path_FFMPEG, string strParam)
{
    try
    {
        Process ffmpeg = new Process();
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = Path_FFMPEG;
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = strParam;
        ffmpeg.Start();

        ffmpeg.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encase the file locations in "". Below is a sample of the code ive been using on my site. Without looking through the documentation what is it you are trying to accomplish with the command? If you have an input file (the one being read), then you will also need an output file if you are converting it or making a text document. It seems you haven't specified where the output file will go. My code below will output a thumbnail and definitely works. Hopefully this puts you in the right direction.

```
string ffmpegCompatibleVideoLocation = "\"" + videoLocation + "\"";
string ffmpegCompatibleoutputFile = "\"" + outputFile + "\"";
string thumbargs = String.Format(@"-ss 00:00:10.435 -i {0} -qscale:v 1 -vframes 1 {1}", ffmpegCompatibleVideoLocation, ffmpegCompatibleoutputFile);
```